# User template with recent posts

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm developing a custom theme for Drupal 7. My problem is I don't know how to make a page that shows information about the author, and below the info, a list of the author's articles. (For ex. if I go to user/ i want to see the profile of the user with the given id, and his/her latest posts).
So what would be the best solution for this?
I've tried with creating user-profile.tpl, it's ok, but I dont' know how the get the nodes, and I don't really want to make sql query-s, because I think there is a prettier method for this.
I've tried with Views, too, but I'm new to Drupal and the most of the tutorials/explanations were for drupal 6 (if it's simple with view, please write me a small guide for it).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It'd be better to create a view that takes the uid as an argument.